# Can I replace one Intel Xeon e5-2603v3 with dual E5-2690v4 on HPE server?

Tags: hardware, intel, xeon

I've got an entry level HPE SRV 778640R-B21 which supports dual CPU but comes with an E5-2603v3 (LGA2011-3 / DDR4). It has also 550W power supply.

I want to remove the current cpu and add a pair of E5-2690v4 if it's possible. If the power will be problem I can chose another pair of cpus like 2650 which consume lower watts.

I've googled but there is no clear info/datasheet. Is it possible to upgrade cpu or what would be your choice?

Comment: Are you already running Full Power on the server?  BIOS and OS settings as documented in this book?   https://www.alibris.com/booksearch?keyword=sql+server+hardware+glenn+berry&mtype=B&hs.x=0&hs.y=0&hs=Submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The E5-2690v4 isn't supported in that server at all, probably due to the TDP, but the 2660v4 is supported and is probably the closest to the 2690v4 that will work. You *MAY* be able to get away with that 550W PSU but if I were spending the money on the extra CPUs then I'd be strongly-tempted to add in the 900W redundant PSU option (778640R-B21) too.

Oh and if you ever want to find HP/HPE datasheets the term to google for is 'quickspecs' ok :)

Comment: Intel Xeon E5 2650L V4 seems ok to me, just 65W.